# Why isn't my variable counting correctly?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, variables

I am having a problem with my code below.  When the user selects a RadioButton (such as reload) and clicks the submit button, I want an ammo counter in the screen to increase by 1.  On a RadioButton selection of "fire", I want the ammo counter to decrease by one.

The problem I'm having is the ammo counter seems to be one behind the user selection.  So:

- ammo count = 1: user selects reload
- ammo count = 1: user selects
  reload
- ammo count = 2: user selects fire
- ammo count = 3: user selects
  reload
- ammo count = 2:

^^ see, the ammo count is consistently one behind the user selection.  How can I fix this?

```
   namespace ShotgunApp
{
    public partial class SingleGame : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public static class AmmoCount
        {
            public static int userAmmo = startVars.startAmmo;
            public static int geniusAmmo = startVars.startAmmo;
        }


        public SingleGame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GeniusAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + AmmoCount.geniusAmmo;
            UserAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + AmmoCount.userAmmo;


        }

        private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Move();
        }

        public void Move()
        { 
            if (uReload.IsChecked.HasValue && uReload.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                UserAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + AmmoCount.userAmmo++;

            }
            else if (uShield.IsChecked.HasValue && uShield.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {

            }
            else if (uFire.IsChecked.HasValue && uFire.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                UserAmmo.Text = "ammo: " + AmmoCount.userAmmo--;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AmmoCount.userAmmo++` and `AmmoCount.userAmmo--` (postfix operators) are decrementing and incrementing the variable correctly but they return the previous unchanged values.

You should use the prefix operators: `(++AmmoCount.userAmmo)` and  `(--AmmoCount.userAmmo)`.